# Unable to disable IPv6

Tags: networking, server, grub2, 22.04

I’ve tried everything I could find on permanently disabling IPv6. [This page](https://www.golinuxcloud.com/linux-disable-ipv6/#Method-2_Linux_disable_IPv6_using_GRUB2_configuration_Requires_Reboot) says to edit /etc/default/grub (then update grub and reboot). OK. Did that. And:

```
cat /etc/default/grub | grep ipv6
```

Returns:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="ipv6.disable=1"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="ipv6.disable=1"
```

Great! Should be disabled now! Nope.

```
ip -6 addr
```

Returns:

```
2: enp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 state UP qlen 1000
    inet6 fe80::e654:e8ff:fe0b:52c9/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

[This page](https://itslinuxfoss.com/disable-ipv6-ubuntu-22-04-jammy-jellyfish/) (supposedly specific to Ubuntu Server 22.04) says to add

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
$ net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
$ net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

to /etc/sysctl.conf then apply the changes and restart the network service. Did that. Then this command is supposed to prove that IPv6 is disabled:

```
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/disable_ipv6
```

When it returns “1” (which it does). But still…

```
ip -6 addr
```

Returns

```
2: enp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 state UP qlen 1000
    inet6 fe80::e654:e8ff:fe0b:52c9/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I tried rebooting. Still got the same output from `ip -6 addr`

What am I doing wrong? More importantly, how do I make it right?

Comment: It is disabled. `fe80` is a local address.

Comment: Thank you, @pilot6. :-)